# Back button disappears after creating AppDelegate in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, appdelegate, back-button

I created the structure as below in xcode 8 swift 3.0.

Before I add **AppDelegate** code. Back button still appear fine on Apply, Apply Behalf and Profile controller.

I use segue to open page.

But after I add **AppDelegate** code into Homepage and Login controllers , back button disappears on **Apply, Apply behalf** and **profile** controller page.

Can someone help or explain why is this happening ? How to enable back the back button on apply, apply behalf and profile page ?

Thanks.

[image]

**Home.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var staffNumberLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        staffNumberLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "login") as? String

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "loggedIn")
        if(!isUserLoggedIn){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginview", sender: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logoutData(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "loggedIn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
        let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

**Login.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loginlbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passlbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

    var login: String!
    var pw: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func loginData(_ sender: Any) {

        login = loginLbl.text
        pw = passLbl.text

        if(login == "" || pw == ""){
            return
        }
        else{
            let url     = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let LoginDataToPost = "login=\(login!)&pw=\(pw!)"
            request.httpBody    = LoginDataToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {
                                    let message = Int(json["message"]!)
                                    let login   = json["login"]

                                    if(message == 1) {
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(login, forKey: "login")
                                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                        let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

                                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myViewController
                                        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                                        print("Value for login is : \(login!)")

                                        return
                                    }
                                    else {}
                            }  
                        }  
                        else {}
                    }
                    catch let jsonParse {}
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    } 
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let isUserLoggedIn:Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        if(!isUserLoggedIn) {

            let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
            window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else {
            let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            window!.rootViewController = homePage
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: add some code ?

Comment: wait for a moment

Comment: Question I have - What are you trying to do in appDelegate? How are you performing segue? What is your destination controller for segue?

Comment: i've updated my question . please refer to my code above

Comment: you are making these controllers as a root so it should not have a back button if you push a controller it will again have it. can you show me where first back button comes and when it disappers.

Comment: in my case , which controller is a root ? how to fix it

Comment: @jamilah can you show me where first back button comes and when it disappers.

Comment: @NikunjDamani . i just perform segue on home.swift . . .  but when i add appdelegate in logoutData and loginData function. the back button disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting rootviewcontroller without embedding navigation controller to it in  `logoutData` & `loginData` function.

Use this code :

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: myViewController)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Use this code in AppDelegate:

```
if(!isUserLoggedIn) {

    let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: loginViewController)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
else {
     let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
     let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: homePage)
     appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
     window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: i'm confuse . . how to embed it ? on both controllers or home controllers only ?

Comment: Just write my code after `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` and remove this line `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myViewController`

Comment: You have to use this code in  `loginData` & `logoutData` function. Please inform me if it worked.

Comment: it does not work so far . maybe i'm missing some step .

Comment: let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: And you are using it where?

Comment: Inside logoutData and loginData function

Comment: According to your updated `AppDelgate` code you have to add a navigationvontroller before setting any viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller to enable back button. Because back button only appears when you add navigationcontroller to it.

Comment: Your problem started from appdelegate.

Comment: appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController does not define ?

Comment: How to declare appDelegate.window? . is it the let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate ?

Comment: Yes. You should know that. I'm keeping this code minimal. Use `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` before using `appDelegate.window`

Comment: i see . my bad . let me try it first . i'll let you know if it work

Answer (score 1):

After successful login,try to make NavigationController as rootViewController instead of your ViewController

Your back button will start appearing.

In AppDelegate, in else block, instead of this line

let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

write this

let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController

Inside LoginViewController, in the block if(message == 1)

replace

let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

with

let navController:UINavigationController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController

Also set storyboard identifier for UINavigationController in storyboard to **NavigationController**

Comment: of which line and which swift file do i need to change it ?

Comment: In AppDelegate in else block
Instead of this line

**let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController**

write this

**let homePage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController**

Comment: Also inside LoginViewController, in the block if(message == 1)

replace

**let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController** \n
 
with
**let navController:UINavigationController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController**

Also set storyboard identifier for UINavigationController in storyboard to **NavigationController**

Comment: An error said "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:"

Comment: Please see my updated answer and replace your original code in post with my code and see if it is working

Comment: back button display but when i try to logged in , an error appears . . im not sure why . btw . the problem already solved :) . thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from Home.swift,

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

because its not inheriting the properties of Navigation controller

and add it in Appdelegate.swift file

**For the** other 3 viewcontrollers, you need to add the Navigation controller between eachSegway in order to inherit it or code the button by instantiating the viewcontrollers respectively

Comment: If possible, Can you update the above code on your answer ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

OR:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Or, if you just want to disable the button without hiding it, you can use this.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: @Dude question in swift not objective c